# Como resolver o "Tempo de Limite Excedido" neste código?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Formato de entrada :**

A entrada consiste de uma série de pares de inteiros i e j, um par de inteiros por linha. Todos os inteiros serão menores que 1.000.000 e maiores que 0.

Perceba que a entrada só termina quando não houveram mais números. Descubra como fazer o seu programa funcionar nesse caso. Cada linguagem tem uma forma diferente de ler enquanto ainda houver entrada a ser lida.

**Formato de saída:**

Para cada par de inteiros i e j, imprima i e j na mesma ordem na qual eles aparecem na entrada e então imprima o máximo "tamanho de ciclo" encontrado. Esses 3 números devem ser separados por um espaço, com todos os 3 números em uma linha e sendo uma linha de saída para cada linha da entrada.

```
def sequencia_de_collatz(i):
    listanum = [i]
    if i < 1:
        return []
    while i > 1:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            i = i / 2
        else:
            i = 3 * i + 1
        listanum.append(i)
    return listanum


inteiro_i = inteiro_j = maior = 0
while True:
    try:
        inteiro_i, inteiro_j = map(int, input().split())
        if inteiro_i < inteiro_j:
            for n in range(inteiro_i, inteiro_j + 1):
                tamanho_do_ciclo = len(sequencia_de_collatz(n))
                if tamanho_do_ciclo > maior:
                    maior = tamanho_do_ciclo
            print(inteiro_i, inteiro_j, maior)
            maior = 0
        else:
            for n in range(inteiro_j, inteiro_i+1):
                tamanho_do_ciclo = len(sequencia_de_collatz(n))
                if tamanho_do_ciclo > maior:
                    maior = tamanho_do_ciclo
            print(inteiro_i, inteiro_j, maior)
            maior = 0
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Comment: Cê tá ligado que o conteúdo dentro do try nunca vai disparar exceção correto? Logo nunca vai cair no break que vai sair do while True

Comment: favor identar o arquivo corretamente - identaççao em Python não é um opcional para deixar bonito - como está o que temos aí é um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: @FourZeroFive a plataforma que o código será executado fará com que ele dê um EOFError, por isso esse "except".

Comment: @jsbueno o "tab" n faz indentação aqui e quando dou espaço o código vira um texto, por isso ficou assim.

Comment: Arrume a identação - você edita o código no seu editor normal, cola o código formatado aqui, e ou usa o botão  de  `{}` ou põe o código entre marcas de três acentos graves - \'\'\' . Não dá pra responder uma pergunta se não dá pra ler o código. (nesse caso até daria pra entender, mas ninguém é obrigado, não é?)

Comment: @jsbueno acho que agora está certo .